# C# WPF image zoom animation via code

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi I wish to zoom to image to specific point with animation, and it does not work.

XAML:

```xaml
<Window x:Class="AnimationTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="720" Width="1280">
    <Grid>
        <Image Height="681" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="image1" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1258" Source="/AnimationTest;component/Images/world.jpg" />
        <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1171,12,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

CS:

```csharp
namespace AnimationTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow: Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation();
            da.From = 0;
            da.To = 1000;
            da.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            image1.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.CenterXProperty, da);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? What exactly does not work? Any exceptions?

Comment: Nothing happens when I click the button

Comment: I guess you use the wrong property, your code works when I use something like `Image.WidthProperty`. Don't you use ScaleTransform as an object of `Image.RenderTransformProperty` usually?

Comment: You can't animate the `CenterX` property of a ScaleTransform on an Image control. An image *is not a* ScaleTransform. And how would you expect to "zoom", when you just animate the x coordinate of a center point. Please explain what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have created simple sample for your requirement.use RenderTransformOrigin to scale to your image from centerpoint(0.5,0.5)

```
XAML

  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Slider x:Name="zoomSlider" Minimum="0" Maximum="10" Value="1"  />
    <Image Source="Jellyfish.jpg" Grid.Row="1">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=zoomSlider,Path=Value}" ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=zoomSlider,Path=Value }"/>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
</Grid>
```